Organic Chia seeds producing beefsteak plant instead of Chia
I bought some of Great Value brand's organic Chia seeds and I planted them directly into the ground, they are now 2½feet tall but when I take a photo and search online to identify the plant(was bored one day and began snapping pics of all the plants I have, weeds and all), it comes up 'beefsteak plant' or 'shiso' or 'Korean perilla[mint] ', but nothing even close to Chia... any suggestions?


Hi Mark, a photo would really help

Ok picture is up.  Today it identified as 'Mealy Cup Sage,' 'scarlet sage', and beefsteak plant

It looks very much like perilla frutescens, an Asian invasive plant. It’s started to flower, so the best thing you can do is pull it up, bag it in a black plastic bag and leave it there until the seeds are no longer viable.
